# Is it possible to create an image with C++?

Tags: c++, image, file

Can you create a PNG, GIF, etc with C++ on windows?

If it's possible, how?  For an example how can you make a png image just one solid color.

Just a "hello world" example would be great...

Comment: You can write binary data to a file using the input/output library, so, yes, you can create images in C++.  What exactly do you want to do with these images that you are going to create?  On what platform(s) does your software need to run?  Without more details, it's quite difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Re creating/writing binary output - to get a feel for a simple image format, check http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/.  (JPEG is massively more complicated.)  The libraries suggested below are a more practical approach for a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When someone asks you about Hello world, just say Hello world ...

```
#include "opencv/cxcore.h"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image(480, 640, CV_8UC3);
    cv::putText(image, "Hello world", cvPoint(320, 200), 
        CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, cvScalar(255, 0, 0));
    cv::imwrite("output.tif", image);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For PNG, try out the PNGWriter library: http://pngwriter.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do so. Some libraries for image manipulation include [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)/[GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) (same API), [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/), and [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). OpenCV is by far the most powerful but also the most difficult to use. CImg is probably the easiest to use, and I would strongly recommend it for beginners... you basically create an instance of the CImg<pixel_type> type, fill in the pixels, and then call "save", which will automatically deduce the type and knows how to encode it based on the file extension you give it.

Comment: how to get the size of a png image in c++?

Answer (score 1):

Images are just binary files and C++ can easily write binary files.  Image formats include many complicated compression algorithms so doing so is not always easy.

Its generally best to use a C++ library which can handle the loading/saving of such files for you so you can worry about more important things like you'd actually like these pictures to have in them.

[Imaghttp://www.imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org) is a popular one used by several open source projects but there are many others.